# How do you make a sharp angle with Bezier cruve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image]

There inside blue circle, I need to make a sharp corner, not round corner.
How do you do it?

Answer (score 4):

Pressing <kbd>V</kbd> will give you a menu to change the handle type, choose "Free". Then you can move the handles fpr the control points independently.